# calculate ESS IV initialization vector for aes-cbc essiv encryption

Tags: cbc, initialization-vector

I want to do block level encrypton on my ext4 image file system with aes-cbc-essiv

How can I find/calculate the the ESSIV needed for encryption?

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia has this documented.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#Encrypted_salt-sector_initialization_vector_.28ESSIV.29)

Essentially: Let $\text{SN}$ by the current sector number encoded as a 128-bit integer. Let $K$ be the key used for encryption. Let $\operatorname{hash}(\cdot)$ be a hash function, which is specified in the cipher name.

Now the $\text{IV}$ is computed as $\operatorname{IV}(\text{SN})=E_{\operatorname{hash}(K)}(\text{SN})$.

The relevant code can be found for [the key-calculation](https://github.com/mbroz/cryptsetup/blob/master/lib/crypto_backend/crypto_storage.c#L83) and for [the actual IV](https://github.com/mbroz/cryptsetup/blob/master/lib/crypto_backend/crypto_storage.c#L162).